# Как в Wordpress плагине сделать вкладки в меню

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я пишу плагин для Wordpress, сейчас стоит задача сделать кладки в пункте меню.

В данный момент Индексный файлик выглядит так:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page_1' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page_1(){
    add_menu_page( 'Обратный звонок', 'Обратный звонок ',       'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_callback.php',    '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );
    add_menu_page( 'Расчет стоимости', 'Расчет стоимости ',     'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_calc.php',        '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );
    add_menu_page( 'Контакты', 'Контакты ',                     'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_contacts.php',    '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );
    add_menu_page( 'Вакансии', 'Вакансии ',                     'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_career.php',      '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );
    add_menu_page( 'Вопрос', 'Вопрос ',                         'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_ask.php',         '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );
    add_menu_page( 'Спецтехника', 'Спецтехника ',               'manage_options', 'core_plugin/views/view_order.php',       '', plugins_url( 'core_plugin/img/img.png' ), 3 );

}
```

Но я бы хотел чтобы эти пункты были дочерними

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_submenu_page

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример из вашего кода.

```html
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page_1' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page_1()
{

     add_menu_page( 'Название меню', 'Название меню', 'manage_options', 'name_of_plugin', 'name_of_plugin_main_function' );
    
    add_submenu_page('name_of_plugin', 'Название меню', 'Обратный звонок', 'manage_options', 'name_of_plugin_callback', 'name_of_plugin_callback_function');
    
    add_submenu_page('name_of_plugin', 'Название меню', 'Расчет стоимости', 'manage_options', 'name_of_plugin_call', 'name_of_plugin_call_function');

}

function name_of_plugin_main_function()
{
    // страница главного меню

}

function name_of_plugin_callback_function()
{
    // страница Обратный звонок

}

function name_of_plugin_call_function()
{
    // страница Расчет стоимости

}
```